# OpenShift freezes at nextjs build phase with message "Creating an optimized production build ..."

Tags: openshift, next.js

I'm trying the OpenShift Online version with two free evaluation months, my evalution stopped very early : I'm unable to get my app online since in the logs it freezes at te compile phase. Seeams to be a RAM issue, but since I don't have control over the ram, does anyone have suggestions?

These are the logs just before it hangs up:

```
added 915 packages from 491 contributors and audited 8414 packages in 63.205s
found 0 vulnerabilities

npm timing npm Completed in 63927ms
npm info ok 
---> Building in production mode
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.9.0
npm info using node@v10.16.0
npm info lifecycle weally@0.1.0~prebuild: weally@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle weally@0.1.0~build: weally@0.1.0

> weally@0.1.0 build /opt/app-root/src
> next build

Creating an optimized production build ...
```

The process is running fro three days now, it seams it's doing things because the processor graphs shows ups and downs, the memory is locked at 530Mb

[image]

Here's my build config:

```
kind: BuildConfig
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: weallynode
  namespace: weally
  selfLink: /apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/weally/buildconfigs/weallynode
  uid: 8c6cf6ec-aa2d-11e9-9f6f-0a580a810073
  resourceVersion: '1319487'
  creationTimestamp: '2019-07-19T14:00:21Z'
  labels:
    app: weallynode
spec:
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'weallynode:latest'
  resources: {}
  successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 2
  strategy:
    type: Source
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        namespace: openshift
        name: 'nodejs:10'
  postCommit: {}
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://1vu@bitbucket.org/1vu/weally.git'
    sourceSecret:
      name: weallygit
  triggers:
    - type: ImageChange
      imageChange:
        lastTriggeredImageID: >-
          image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/nodejs@sha256:9dce2f60b87b2eea351213c3d142716c0a70c894df8b3d2d4425b4933b8f6221
    - type: ConfigChange
  runPolicy: Serial
status:
  lastVersion: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your buildConfig resources section ? Refer [Setting Build Resources](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/builds/advanced_build_operations.html#build-resources) for more details.

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "BuildConfig"
metadata:
  name: "sample-build"
spec:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: "100m" 
      memory: "256Mi"
```

If the limits section is configured by specific sizes, then you can change them.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Hi Daein, 

I added the build config in the question, there's no resources section in it, so it is limited by the "free trial limit" I think

Comment: They write: By default, builds are completed by pods using unbound resources, such as memory and CPU. These resources can be limited by specifying resource limits in a project’s default container limits.

Comment: Then you can check the project limitation using `oc get namespace <your projectname> -o yaml`. But ... I'm not sure whether web ui can see the project details on OCP online ...

Comment: Refer [Viewing Limit Ranges](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/compute_resources.html#dev-viewing-limit-ranges) for project resources limitation.

Comment: Thanks @Daein, but how could that help me build my project?
I have these limits : for the minimum and maximum
Pod                    memory    100Mi  1Gi
Container              cpu       7m     2   

does it simply mean I cannot have my project on openshift online?

Comment: Personally I think it might be helpful to your build, if you can remove the limitation. But if you cannot , as you mentioned it can not build on free tier or you had better to ask for the support desk.